# Событие js onload для flash

Tags: javascript, flash

Как можно узнать из js, что флеш файл подключенный в теге `<object>` полностью загружен и готов к использованию. Если нет решения только на js, может сама флешка может оповестить о загрузки, с помощью моста или еще как то?

UPD

Есть либа https://github.com/faisalman/flash-cookie-js/

код подгрузки swf файла https://github.com/faisalman/flash-cookie-js/blob/master/src/js/flash-cookie.js

Там готовность флешки определяется после 200ms после готовности body, но 200 не всегда достаточно, вот я и хочу сделать однозанчно по готовности(чтоб наверняка и не гадать с таймером), кстати и по `window.onload` флешка тоже еще не всегда работает.

Comment: А `onload` не походит? `window.onload`.

Comment: Вообщем то подходит, но вот хотелось то узнать конкретно для флеш

Comment: Автору отклонённых правок: см. [Излишнее внутристрочное форматирование](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1328/)